# Padding is invalid and cannot be removed. on cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock(); in Decrypt Method i got this exception

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace GUISimpleTCPClient
{

    public partial class GUISimpleTCPClient : Form
    {

        TcpClient client=null;
        NetworkStream stream;
        StreamReader reader;
        StreamWriter writer;
        public GUISimpleTCPClient()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                client=new TcpClient(ipAddress.Text,Convert.ToInt32(port.Text));
                listBox1.Items.Add("Connected to Server");
                stream = client.GetStream();
                reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                string msg = reader.ReadLine();
                listBox1.Items.Add("Recieved form server:");
                listBox1.Items.Add(msg);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string msg = M.Text;
            SymmetricAlgorithm symmetricAlgorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("password");


            symmetricAlgorithm.Key = GetLegalKey("PASSWORD");
            symmetricAlgorithm.IV = GetLegalIV();
            byte[] cipher = Encrypt(symmetricAlgorithm, data);
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            msg = enc.GetString(cipher);

           // System.Text.Encoding encoding=new System.Text.Encoding() ;
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding denc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
           Byte[] dec_data = denc.GetBytes(msg);
            string decode = Decrypt(symmetricAlgorithm, dec_data);

            try
            {

                writer.WriteLine(msg);
                writer.Flush();
                msg = reader.ReadLine();
                if (msg.Length!=0)
                listBox1.Items.Add(decode);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private static byte[] Encrypt(SymmetricAlgorithm symmetricAlgorithm,

             byte[] data)
        {

            //   FileStream outStream = File.OpenWrite(outPath);



            ICryptoTransform transform = symmetricAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor();

            MemoryStream t = new MemoryStream();

            CryptoStream cryptoStream =

                new CryptoStream(t, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);



            Byte[] inFile = data;
            // File.ReadAllBytes(inPath);



            cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            cryptoStream.Close();
            return t.ToArray();

        }



        private static string Decrypt(SymmetricAlgorithm symmetricAlgorithm,

            byte[] cipher)
        {

            ICryptoTransform transform = symmetricAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor();



            // Stream inStream = File.OpenRead(inPath);
            MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream();

            CryptoStream cryptoStream =

                new CryptoStream(inStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);



            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[100];
            cryptoStream.Write(cipher, 0, cipher.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            //Console.WriteLine();
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inStream.ToArray());


            // int length = cryptoStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);



            //  Stream outStream = File.OpenWrite(outPath);

            /* while (length > 0)

             {

                 outStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

                 length = cryptoStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

             }*/


            //inStream.Close();

            // outStream.Close();

        }

        private byte[] GetLegalKey(string Key)
        {
            SymmetricAlgorithm symmetricAlgorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();
            string sTemp = Key;
            symmetricAlgorithm.GenerateKey();
            byte[] bytTemp = symmetricAlgorithm.Key;
            int KeyLength = bytTemp.Length;

            if (sTemp.Length > KeyLength)
                sTemp = sTemp.Substring(0, KeyLength);
            else if (sTemp.Length < KeyLength)
                sTemp = sTemp.PadRight(KeyLength, ' ');

            return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sTemp);
        }

        private byte[] GetLegalIV()
        {
            string initialIV = "12345678";
            SymmetricAlgorithm symmetricAlgorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();
            // The initial string of IV may be modified with any data you like
            string sTemp = initialIV;
            symmetricAlgorithm.GenerateIV();
            byte[] bytTemp = symmetricAlgorithm.IV;
            int IVLength = bytTemp.Length;

            if (sTemp.Length > IVLength)
                sTemp = sTemp.Substring(0, IVLength);
            else if (sTemp.Length < IVLength)
                sTemp = sTemp.PadRight(IVLength, ' ');

            return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sTemp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you shorten this code snippet?

Comment: This is no different from your previous, closed question. If you have a question to ask then please ask it; don't just post large chunks of code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052593/padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed-on-cryptostream-flushfinalblock

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
byte[] cipher = Encrypt(symmetricAlgorithm, data);
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
msg = enc.GetString(cipher);
```

**Never, ever do this.**

The encrypted data is *not* an ASCII-encoded string, so don't treat it that way. Use base64 instead. So this snippet should be:

```
byte[] cipher = Encrypt(symmetricAlgorithm, data);    
msg = Convert.ToBase64String(cipher);
```

and the reverse should be:

```
byte[] dec_data = Convert.FromBase64String(msg);
```

You should never treat opaque binary data as if it were really encoded text. It's like trying to load an MP3 file as if it were a JPG. It's not - you'll lose data.

Comment: i did this but now there is a new problem :
Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.

Comment: @Nahel: Well, I suggest you investigate what's wrong with your encryption/decryption code by trying to decrypt the byte array *immediately*, without performing *any* kind of conversion.